# Differences between the different installers of SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server-express

I'm trying to understand the differences between the different installers of SQL Server 2014 Express.  If you are able to tell me whatever you can or find documentation on them, I'd appreciate it.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42299

```
Express 32BIT WoW64\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe
Express 32BIT\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe
Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe
ExpressAdv 32BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe
ExpressAdv 64BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
ExpressAndTools 32BIT\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe
ExpressAndTools 64BIT\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe
LocalDB 32BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi
LocalDB 64BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi
MgmtStudio 32BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe
MgmtStudio 64BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Did you refer to Details ?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) It covers all the details.

> MgmtStudio 32BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe
>
> MgmtStudio 64BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

These are standalone installations for SSMS - a GUI tool to manage sql server.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

- Express 32BIT WoW64\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing the 32-bit version of SQL Server Express, just the engine, on a 64-bit OS in WoW64 mode. WoW64 mode is [described in excruciating detail here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Express 32BIT\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing the 32-bit version of SQL Server Express, just the engine, on a 32-bit OS.
- Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing the 64-bit version of SQL Server Express, just the engine, on a 64-bit OS.
- ExpressAdv 32BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing a 32-bit engine and advanced services on a 32-bit operating system. ["Advanced services" are explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248(v=sql.105).aspx).
- ExpressAdv 64BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing a 64-bit engine and advanced services on a 64-bit operating system. ["Advanced services" are explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248(v=sql.105).aspx).
- ExpressAndTools 32BIT\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing a 32-bit engine and tools (most importantly SSMS and Profiler) on a 32-bit operating system. ["Express With Tools" is explained here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239408(v=sql.100).aspx).
- ExpressAndTools 64BIT\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing a 64-bit engine and tools (most importantly SSMS and Profiler) on a 64-bit operating system. ["Express With Tools" is explained here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239408(v=sql.100).aspx).
- LocalDB 32BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi

  > This is for installing LocalDB on a 32-bit operating system. [LocalDB is described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).
- LocalDB 64BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi

  > This is for installing LocalDB on a 64-bit operating system. [LocalDB is described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).
- MgmtStudio 32BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing a standalone Management Studio on a 32-bit operating system.
- MgmtStudio 64BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

  > This is for installing a standalone Management Studio on a 64-bit operating system.